# WordPress theme upload goes wrong

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to transfer my clients new site to their domain. While uploading the theme I accidentally went to another page while it was updating plug-in translations, now I get this error when activating the theme:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_add_inline_script() in /home/pxxr228380/domains/braincaps.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mrbara/inc/frontend/header.php on line 49

Reuploading the theme doesn't fix it and the original site still works fine. How do I fix this? The line in question is: wp_add_inline_script( 'mrbara', mrbara_footer_scripts() );

Note: I'm installing it on an existing Wordpress installation with installed plug-ins, could it be a plug-in causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_add_inline_script()` should normally be defined by the time the theme's code starts running. Is the site running an older version of WordPress? The undefined function was introduced in WordPress 4.5, [according to the docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/), so if you're running an older version, updating WordPress should help.

You also asked whether a plugin could cause it -- sometimes a plugin can cause core parts of WordPress to load in a different order, which can cause some functions to be missing when they should normally be defined, but I don't think it can cause this particular issue, since this function is defined fairly early when WordPress is loading.